# How to plot a probability mass function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and would like to know how to plot a graph when it states

```
a =  -1    0   1       2       3
----------------------------------
p(a)1/24  1/2  1/4   1/6     1/24
```

Any tips on how to do it would be helpful!

Comment: Something like this: `a = [-1 0 1 2 3];
p = [1/24 1/2 1/4 1/6 1/24];
plot(a,p)` ?

Comment: To add to Benoit_11's comment: since it's a probabilty _mass_ function, maybe use `stem` instead of `plot`

Comment: There are manifold ways to plot stuff: http://de.mathworks.com/discovery/gallery.html
(Although a `bar` plot is probably what you want)

Answer (score 1):

For a probability mass function, I would use `bar`

```
>> a = [-1 0 1 2 3]; p = [1/24 1/2 1/4 1/6 1/24]; bar(a,p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because this shows up high when searching for *MATLAB PMF*, an alternative way to plot discrete probability distributions is the `stem` function.

```
a = [-1 0 1 2 3]; p = [1/24 1/2 1/4 1/6 1/24];
stem(a,p);
set(gca, 'xlim', [-1.5 3.5]);
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why `set(gca, ...)` instead of the more concise `xlim([-1.5 3.5])`?

Comment: @chsk, no particular reason. I often work on figures with multiple axes, so I've just got into the habbit of always using the full `set(ax, ...)` function, which makes it more explicit which axis you're working on, rather than the shorthand, which only works on `gca`. Personal preference, but in this case, sure you can use `xlim` if you prefer.